# Using yarn, how to update package.json with actual version installed of packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm working on a project where dependencies version are not strictly fixed (using the ^), like so:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1"
}
...
```

Now, I'd like to strictly fix all version (remove the ^) but I'd like to keep the version actually installed (and saved in `yarn.lock`) at the moment and write it to `package.json`.

For example, for `react: ^16.13.1`, installed version is `16.14.0`.
So I'd like my `package.json` to be:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "16.14.0"
}
...
```

Is there a command to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution came from [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).

Running this command, it updates my package.json with latest minor version for all packages:

```
ncu -t minor -u
```

Then, a little `yarn install` to actually install these packages and you can safely remove all the `^` of your package.json.